# Bind Database to Objects

Tags: database, vb.net, object

I don't know if this is even the correct terminology but I was wondering if it is possible to bind a row (of data) from a database to an object. I am working on a school project and we have decided to create this application to track a user's BMI/BMR and compare it to the amount of calories they have input. The program doesn't go too in depth so it does not store the calories consumed in the database.

So here is my problem. I have a row in my database:

`First_Name` -- `Last_Name` -- `Height_Inches` -- `Weight_Pounds`

And I guess what I am thinking I want my program to do is if I have an object with properties for FirstName, LastName, HeightInches, WeightPounds, is to somehow query the database for one row and put the values into the object. All we have learned so far is binding the data with controls which doesn't really help in my case since the work is going to be done behind the scenes.

Sorry if this is vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know VB.Net's syntax very well, so here's some C# that might help :)  Should be easy enough to translate.  Also, it's been awhile since I've done raw ADO.Net so it might not be entirely accurate.

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringGoesHere"))
        {
            string query = @"select First_Name, Last_Name, Height_Inches, Weight_Pounds from table_name";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            BMIObject bmi = new BMIObject();
            bmi.FirstName = (string)reader["First_Name"];
            bmi.LastName = (string)reader["Last_Name"];
            bmi.Weight = (int)reader["Weight_Pounds"];
            bmi.Height = (int)reader["Height_Inches"];

            reader.Close();

            return bmi;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand C# just as well as I know VB but for my class I'm forced to use the latter. Unfortunately, I am unable to test this until Saturday when I am at my development computer and with my group. And I've searched online for this and I'm not sure if I put in the wrong search terms but do you have a reference for this kind of query/technique?

Comment: There are any number of others ways to go at this problem - you could get fancy and use something like Linq to Sql or Entity Framework and have it map your table for you, but that seems like overkill for this :)