# What is the difference between using a DataContext class and SqlConnection?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, ado.net, database-connection

This might be a very vague question but I guess I don't really understand what is going on. I asked a [question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527884/bind-database-to-objects/9527984#comment12070524_9527984) where I was told a simple way to "bind data to objects" is to just run a SqlConnection(*connectionString*). The response also included a comment saying I could get fancy with L2S and Entity Frameworks, so I looked deeper into those. It seems all you have to do with the DataContext object is point to the database. Why would SqlConnection be a benefit?

What is the difference (or pros/cons) of using either one of these? Is one more "standard"? Is one more modern?

**P.S.** I asked a lot of questions that don't all need to be answered. I just wanted to add some clarity to my question and how much I don't really understand this topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SqlConnection` is part of the base, raw ADO.NET class library - the SQL Server part of that library, really. This is the foundation of all data access in .NET.

With raw ADO.NET, you're pretty "bare-bones" and close to the metal - you have to create your SQL queries and execute them, you get back rows and columns, very much like a relational database will give you.

Pros: really close to the SQL, really powerful, best performance
Cons: harder to write, more "glue" code, less type safety, tighter coupling to the underlying database structure

---

`DataContext` (Linq-to-SQL) or `ObjectContext` (Entity Framework) are higher level abstractions - they sit on top of ADO.NET, but they (Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework) offer so called ORM capabilities - here, you're not really dealing with raw SQL statements and rows/columns, instead, those code generators will create an abstraction layer for you - which is built up from .NET objects. Each table in the database will be turned into a corresponding .NET class, with properties for all the columns in that table.

Also, with L2S and EF, you're typically using `LINQ` to query - your queries are much more C# like code, and L2s / EF will handle translating those queries you express in C# into actual SQL statements that SQL Server will execute.

Pros: much easier to work with, much nicer to handle (objects with properties vs. raw rows/columns), type safety, ability to query with LINQ, higher dev productivity
Cons: another layer means more translations, a hit on performance, not well suited for certain things (like bulk operations)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is something I can probably search on my own from here on out, but do you know of any good resources on these topics besides MSDN? This is my next "area of study" so I figured I better get it down right.

Comment: @AdamBeck: MSDN is definitely your first place to go; then if you're looking into EF, go to http://thedatafarm.com/blog/ - Julie Lerman's blog, she's the Queen of EF ;-) Also: if you're on ASP.NET, check out http://www.asp.net which has lots of data-related stuff, too (videos, tutorials)

Comment: This is a good explanation! Thanks @marc_s this helps me alot